# wxWidgets wxRichTextCtrl no horizontal scrolling

Tags: wxwidgets

Why horizontal scrolling doesn't work ?

```
wxRichTextCtrl richtext = new wxRichTextCtrl(splitter, wxID_ANY, wxEmptyString, 
           wxPoint(5, 5), wxSize(200, 150), wxRE_MULTILINE | wxHSCROLL);
```

Comment: what wx version? what OS are you trying it on? what exactly doesn't work - please be more specific.

Comment: Version 3.1.1   | Windows 10 | Visual Studio 2017 | Scroll bar does not appear, text wrapped

Comment: does the sample works for you? are you trying to enter new text or load some file from the disk? What type of textr you trying - regular, html or xml?

Comment: I enter data on the keyboard. Here is my .exe https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wSvH3dzOyTut18b9U8W2tPYaYqZbD_G_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: did you try the sample?

Comment: Yes, I tried the 'richtext' sample by adding wxRE_MULTILINE | wxHSCROLL

Comment: the question was not whether you tried or not - the question was whether the sample worked for you as you would expect it to.

Comment: of course it doesn't work

Comment: well, unfortunately I don't have a crystall ball to see what you see. But you did a right thing by opening the ticket on the trac.wxwidgets.org.